# AngularJS Transition on click

Tags: angularjs, transition

I am kind of new with angular and I found this way to use ng-click and ng-show to show the div with information in when the user clicks the h3. 
The only problem is that it just shows up and I would like is it fades in or slides down to be visible. :) 
Is this gonna work or should I do another way??

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div>
        <h3 class="no-margin-bottom toggleText" ng-click="showInfoHe = !showInfoHe"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hälsoinformation</h3>
        <hr class="no-margin-top hr-line">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 margin-top" style="border: 1px solid purple" ng-show="showInfoHe">
    <div class="row cats-attributes">
        <p>info</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need [`ngAnimate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

Comment: Check this [`ngAnimate` tutorial here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-animations-in-angularjs-with-nganimate--cms-28593)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without ngAnimate,
by using css transitions and ngClass
what you want to do on click set a variable to true and then have a class that has opacity:1.

so

```
<div class="parent-div" ng-click="yourVariable = true">
  <div class="child" ng-class={'opacity-class': yourVariable}>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then in the css

```
.parent-div {
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s;

}
.parent-div.child {
    opacity:0;
  }
.opacity-class {
   opacity:  1;
}
```

EDIT:
here is an applied solution to the html structure you provided

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div>
        <h3 class="no-margin-bottom toggleText" ng-click="showInfoHe = !showInfoHe"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Hälsoinformation</h3>
        <hr class="no-margin-top hr-line">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show-info-container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 margin-top show-info" style="border: 1px solid purple" ng-class="{'opacity-class':showInfoHe}">
      <div class="row cats-attributes">
          <p>info</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.show-info-container {
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s;

}
.show-info {
    opacity:0;
  }
.opacity-class {
   opacity:  1;
}
```

notice i added a container div and removed the ng-show

Comment: you can also do the slide down effect with @keyframes animation, i wont go into details but its the general same approach. good luck :)

Comment: thanks! :) but how does that work with ng-click that i already have on the parent? The one that makes the child div show with ng-show.

Comment: and don't forget to approve the answer if it helped you :)